# How to schedule a periodic background work to activate at fixed times?

Tags: java, android, backgroundworker

I want to push a notification every 12 hours at fixed times (lets say for an example, 9am and 9pm, every day). This is my current doWork() code:

```
  @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        database.child("business_users").child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                user = snapshot.getValue(BusinessUser.class);
                if(user.isNotifications()==true)
                {
                    if(user.getRatingsCount() > user.getLastKnownRC())
                    {
                        theDifference = user.getRatingsCount() - user.getLastKnownRC();
                        notification();
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        Log.i("BackgroundWork" , "notif sent");
        return Result.success();
    }
```

`

and this is the work creation code:

```
public void FirstTimeWork ()
     {
         PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest =
                 new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWork.class, 12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                         .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                         .addTag("notif")
                         .build();
     }
```

I saw some people doing it with calendar but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: You may want to give a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks. You just have to enable scheduling in the spring application, then use @Scheduled annotation on the method you want to execute at a given predeterminated time, and finally configure the schedule itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution, using calendar:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + 1);
}
```

and the initial delay is set like so:

```
.setInitialDelay(calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

and this seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

The @EnableScheduling annotation is used to enable the scheduler for your application. This annotation should be added into the main Spring Boot application class file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

The @Scheduled annotation is used to trigger the scheduler for a specific time period.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * 9 * * ?")
public void cronJobSch() throws Exception {
}
```

The following is a sample code that shows how to execute the task every minute starting at 9:00 AM and ending at 9:59 AM, every day

```
package com.tutorialspoint.demo.scheduler;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Scheduler {
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 * 9 * * ?")
   public void cronJobSch() {
      System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
   }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please note that the code example is to ilustrate on how to use the Spring Scheduled capability only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `Timer`. Then, your background job must be implemented in a subclass to `TimerTask` in the overridden method `public void run()`, e.g.:

```
public class BackgroundWork extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your background work here
        Log.i("BackgroundWork" , "notif sent");
    }
}
```

You can schedule this job as follows:

```
// void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)
Date date = new Date( 122, 04, 02, 9, 00 );
(new Timer()).scheduleAtFixedRate(new BackgroundWork(), date, 43200000L);
```

Timer starts a new thread to execute this job. You can cancel it, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScheduledExecutorService

```
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService
                = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(CORE_POOL_SIZE);

        // Calculate initial day based on the current time
        Long initalDelay = 0l;

        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture =
                scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(doWork(), initalDelay, 12l, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```